# Project/Reference extension

Tags: contao

I would like to create (or find) an extension where I can fill in with projects/referneces. Actually it would be something the same like the News modul, just with some extra custom fields like categories, etc. with a list FE Modul and a Reader for the single project page. Does anybody knows about an extension like this, or what I can use for a good starting point?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any extension but if you don't like the idea of creating your own extension I would take a look at [metamodels](https://now.metamodel.me/en/home).

I haven't done anything with it yet, but that should be the most flexible solution.

Comment: Thanks. This will be the solution.